# React Native Navigation 5 working on IOS simulator but doesn't work in Android Emulator

Tags: react-native

I was trying to install React Native Navigation 5. It's working on IOS simulator but doesn't work in Android Emulator. Could you please help anyone? Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD1KD.jpg)

Comment: Try uninstall the android app from emulator and reinstall it

Comment: I tried. Same problem.

Comment: did u installed all the libraries required by react navigation

Comment: Yes I did. If you check my screenshot you will see it's displaying on IOS simulator.